# How to implement pow(x) and sqrt(x)?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator, math.sqrt

I tried looking for a similar answer, but didn't find anything. So here goes.

I am currently tasked with creating a simple calculator with a GUI in Python using the tkinter tools.

I was almost done when I ran into some problems implementing pow(x) and sqrt(x) and having them work properly.

**This is the function I used for my operand buttons:**

```
def press(num):
   global expression
   expression = expression + str(num)
   equation.set(expression)
```

**This worked fine for all the simple stuff like '+':**

```
plus = Button(gui, text=' + ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("+"), height=1, width=7)
```

But now I still need to add pow and sqrt by importing from math and connect them to the buttons. I tried using the same "press" function, but with sqrt I am getting a  ValueError.

```
powx = Button(gui, text=' pow(x) ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("pow("), height=1, width=7)
powx.grid(row=4, column=4)
sqrt = Button(gui, text=' sqrt(x) ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("sqrt("), height=1, width=7)
sqrt.grid(row=5, column=4)
```

**sqrt Error Code:**
TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

**Equals:**

```
def equalpress():
    try:
        global expression
        total = str(eval(expression))
        equation.set(total)
        expression = ""

    except ZeroDivisionError: 
        equation.set(" Cant divide through Zero! ")
        expression = ""

    except SyntaxError: 
        equation.set(" SyntaxError! ")
        expression = ""
```

I would really apreciate some advice. Thanks!
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ddu2.png)

Comment: `press()` puts the opening parenthesis, but when do you add the closing paren?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're replacing the built-in `sqrt()` function when you do:

```
sqrt = Button(gui, text=' sqrt(x) ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("sqrt("), height=1, width=7)
sqrt.grid(row=5, column=4)
```

Now the name `sqrt` refers to your button, not the function. Change the variable name, like you do for the `pow` button.

```
sqrtx = Button(gui, text=' sqrt(x) ', fg='orange', bg='white', command=lambda: press("sqrt("), height=1, width=7)
sqrtx.grid(row=5, column=4)
```

Comment: Oh yeah that definetly solved the sqrt problem. I feel stupid for not realising that for like 2 hours. Thanks!